# Получить имя исполняемого приложения

Tags: c#

Пишу небольшое приложение которое работает с названием файла, но возникла сложность я не могу найти название исполняемого файла, многое перепробовал например:

```
1. string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName( Application.ExecutablePath);
2. string patch = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
3. Application.StartupPath
```

Завершаются ошибками в компиляции.

```
using System;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Text;  

namespace Examples.System.Net  
{  
    public class WebRequestGetExample  
    {  
        public static void Main()  
        {  
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://*******/indata.php?nt=2");  
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;  
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();


            //string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            //string patch = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
            //Console.WriteLine(Application.StartupPath);
            var path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            response.Close();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

в итоге мне нужно indata.php?nt=(название файла)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Если есть ошибки, то приводите текст ошибок в вопросе, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У тебя namespace какой та странный. Попробуй ка вот что

```
using System;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Text;  
using ReflactionNamespace = System.Reflection;
namespace Examples.System.Net  
{  
    public class WebRequestGetExample  
    {  
        public static void Main()  
        {  
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://*******/indata.php?nt=2");  
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;  
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            //string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            //string patch = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
            //Console.WriteLine(Application.StartupPath);
            var path = ReflactionNamespace.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            response.Close();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: выдает error cs0234 имя типа или пространства имен 'reflection' отсутствует в пространстве имен 'Example.System' <пропущена ссылка на сборку?>

Comment: @Keeplod Покажите что вы написали.

Comment: @Keeplod, Изминил код, посмотри

Comment: Работает спасибо большое

Answer (score 8):

библиотека system.dll

код:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

Найдено по запросу "c# get app file name"

Comment: вот такое выкидывает=( 
2.cs(20,4): error CS0201: В качестве оператора могут использоваться выражения
        присваивания, вызова, инкремента, декремента и создания нового объекта
2.cs(20,11): error CS0234: Имя типа или пространства имен 'Diagnostics'
        отсутствует в пространстве имен 'Examples.System' (пропущена ссылка на
        сборку?)

Comment: не подключил нужный референс. Оно должно подчеркнуть и подсказать что нужен  system

Comment: я в нотпаде делаю тут мало что подчеркивают(

Comment: подправил ответ

Answer (score 5):

Если необходимо узнать путь к исполняемому **приложению**, рекомендую использовать

```
string path = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
```

Поясню: код @DIlshod работает с проектом, соответственно, если вы попробуете вынести его в отдельный проект-библиотеку, вызывая этот код из **приложения**, вы будете получать путь до исполняемой assembly, то есть, путь к dll библиотеке (имя будет соответствовать именно *.dll библиотеке, а не *.exe файлу)

Извлекая аргументы командной строки, вы гарантированно заберёте у ОС путь к исполняемому приложению, а не к текущему выполняемому модулю. Решение от @Andrew так же, более правильное, нежели рефлексия.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно только название файла с расширением:

```
$"http://*******/indata.php?nt={System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName.Split('\\').Last()}"
```